# Append an int to a std::string

Tags: c++, std

Why is this code gives an Debug Assertion Fail?

```
   std::string query;
   int ClientID = 666;
   query = "select logged from login where id = ";
   query.append((char *)ClientID);
```

Comment: can you add to definition of ClientID ? is it a std::string or a char * ?

Comment: says invalid null-pointer by the way

Answer (score 230):

The [`std::string::append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) method expects its argument to be a NULL terminated string (`char*`).

There are several approaches for producing a `string` containg an `int`:

- [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

  ```
  #include <sstream>

  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "select logged from login where id = " << ClientID;
  std::string query(s.str());
  ```
- [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (C++11)

  ```
  std::string query("select logged from login where id = " +
                    std::to_string(ClientID));
  ```
- [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

  ```
  #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

  std::string query("select logged from login where id = " +
                    boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ClientID));
  ```

Comment: +1 for boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: +1 for std::to_string

Comment: +1 for clear, clean and complete answer

Comment: std::to_string has no function that requiers an int...

Comment: It does according to the standard (check the reference link).  Your compiler may not implement it yet, however.

Comment: +1 for string stream! Though I am curious, are any of these approaches considered better than the other? For instance is one faster, handle memory better or just better practice?

Comment: `std::to_string()`... exists??? +100

Comment: @Hakon89, VS2010 supports a subset of the std::to_string set, `long long` is one of them: try `std::to_string((long long)ClientID);`

Comment: @Kris, sorry but I can't comment on performance.

Comment: +1 but you forgot `boost::format`!

Comment: These +1 comments are turning into a poll of which option readers like best

Answer (score 9):

You cannot cast an int to a char* to get a string.  Try this:

```
std::ostringstream sstream;
sstream << "select logged from login where id = " << ClientID;
std::string query = sstream.str();
```

[stringstream reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

Comment: Wow... its first time i see istringstream... thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that should be ostringstream. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling that your `ClientID` is not of a string type (zero-terminated `char*` or `std::string`) but some integral type (e.g. `int`) so you need to convert number to the string first:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << ClientID;
query.append(ss.str());
```

But you can use `operator+` as well (instead of `append`):

```
query += ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are casting `ClientID` to char* causing the function to assume its a null terinated char array, which it is not.

from cplusplus.com :

> string& append ( const char * s ); Appends a copy of the string formed
>   by the null-terminated character sequence (C string) pointed by s. The
>   length of this character sequence is determined by the first ocurrence
>   of a null character (as determined by traits.length(s)).

Comment: Ok, i got it. Well how can append to the end an integer value?

Comment: see @hmjd answer down below.. he already covers this.