# Error when concatenating strings (C++)

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to create a string that points to a file and am getting this error:

> .../testApp.cpp:75: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator+'

Here is the line in question:

```
    string path = "images/" + i + ".png";
```

This seems like a fairly simple issue, yet it confounds me. I also included the string header:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std
```

Comment: What is the type of `i`?

Answer (score 5):

or `boost::format`:

```
std::string str = (boost::format("images/%d.png") % i).str();
```

`boost::format(FORMATTED_STIRNG) % .. %.. %..` is for formatted string processing, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). this function gives you back a special boost format which you need to cast to std::string using its `.str()` member function.

Comment: sorry, I considered the syntax to be quite obvious. but I added explanation now.

Comment: Undownvote-upvoted. Try to do this for your future posts as well :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert `i` to a `std::string`:

```
string path = "images/" + boost::lexical_cast<string>(i) + ".png";
```

For other approaches to converting an `int` to a `std::string` see [Append an int to a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `stringstream` instead, `std::string` doesn't support off-the-rack formatting for integers.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "images/" << i << ".png";
std::string path = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to concatenate string literals as if they are `std::string` objects. They are not. In C++ string literals are of type `const char[]`, not `std::string`.

To join two string literals, place them next to each other with no operator:

```
const char* cat = "Hello " "world";
```

To join two `std::string` objects, use `operator+(std::string, std::string)`:

```
std::string hello("hello ");
std::string world("world\n");
std::sting cat = hello + world;
```

There is also an `operator+` to join a string literal and a `std::string`:

```
std::string hello("hello ");
std::string cat = hello + "world\n";
```

There is no `operator+` that takes `std::string` and `int`.

A solution to your problem is to use `std::stringstream`, which takes any `operator<<` that `std::cout` can take:

```
std::stringstream spath;
spath << "images/" << i << ".png";
std::string path = spath.str();
```

Comment: _technicially_ string literals will concatenate with std::string, and with each other (although with a different syntax).  You should reword part 1.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 we get a set of [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) functions that can help converting built in numeric types to std::string. You can use that in your conversion:

```
string path = "images/" + to_string(i) + ".png";
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote all of the other answers, yes, `std::string` doesn't have built in support for appending integers. However, you can add an operator to do just that:

```
template<typename T>
std::string operator +(const std::string &param1, const T& param2)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << param1 << param2;

    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
std::string operator +(const T& param1, const std::string& param2) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << param1 << param2;

    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
std::string& operator +=(std::string& param1, const T& param2) 
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << param1 << param2;

    param1 = ss.str();
    return param1;
}
```

The only real disadvantage to this is you must first cast one of the literals to a string, like this:

```
string s = string("Hello ") + 10 + "World!";
```

Comment: I'd want to test this thoroughly before using it, this could potentially cause certail well defined behavior to suddenly get an ambiguity error.