# How to convert Integer to string

Tags: c++, c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)
>   [Append an int to a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring)

I want to convert integer to string, any one help me for these conversion?

```
itoa(*data->userid,buff1,10);
itoa(*data->userphone,buff2,10);
```

Comment: To everyone who posted answers below, instead of feeding yet another duplicate and chasing SO scores, you'd be better voting to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: three possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For C++, use `std::stringstream` instead.

```
#include <sstream>

//...
std::stringstream ss;
ss << *data->userid;
std::string userId = ss.str();
```

or `std::to_string` if you have access to a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a C++11 compiler with the new [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function you can use that. Otherwise use the `std::stringstream` solution by Luchian.