# How can i create a new string using string modifiers in C++?

Tags: c++, string, writetofile

I want to write a timestamp to a file in a certain format.

Is there a way to create a new string using modifiers (see printf code below)? Or is there another way to use string modifiers in a TextStream?

```
printf("%02d-%02d-%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d\n", 
       st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on your issue? Is this a program which intersects C & C++? Could this be possibly a C example of what you'd like to do in C++? This is an issue I'm taking up, dealing with code examples in other languages than the one the advice is asking for without clarification of the intent. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I wanted use a string stream to write a string to a file in the same format as the printf in my example. Using sprintf makes this possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) instead of `printf`, the string you want is written to a `char` buffer rather than printed.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%02d-%02d-%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d\n", 
        st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

You can also use the [Boost Format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Comment: Aha!! Thanks.. I'm not really familiar with C++. I had tried sprintf before but i apparently used it incorrectly!

Answer (score 5):

A type-safe alternative, with no concerns over buffer size, would be to use [IO manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) either on the output stream directly or on [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << std::setfill('0')
      << std::setw(2) << 1 << ':' // st.wYear, etc
      << std::setw(2) << 97 << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << 4;

    std::cout << s.str() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Additionally, a previous answer that illustrates approaches for getting an `int` into a `std::string`: [Append an int to a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313)