# OStringStream and Namespaces Issue C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, ostringstream

so I wanted to convert an integer into a string but using itoa isn't standard so through my research I figured the best way to do it would be to use OStringStream. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>


std::string plusMinus(int x) {

    std::ostringstream x_str;
    // more code here obviously

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // some cin/cout functions here
}
```

I get an error on the "std::ostringstream line: "Implicit instantiation of undefined template". What does this mean? I've tried putting "using namespace std;" at the top but it has no effect.

Comment: To convert an `int` to `std::string` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313 for some solutions.

Comment: In modern C++, say `std::to_string(x)`, from the `<string>` header.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add the following include:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was under the <iostream> header

Answer (score 5):

You need to include header `<sstream>`. You should probably also include `<string>`, although that isn't strictly necessary given the string-returning `ostringstream::str()` method.