# How to convert boost::uintmax_t to std::string

Tags: c++, boost

`boost::filesystem::file_size()` returns `boost::uintmax_t`. So, How to convert `boost::uintmax_t` to `std::string`?

Comment: I'm guessing both `std::to_string` and `boost::lexical_cast` do the job.

Comment: Some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313

Comment: std::to_string not works but boost::lexical_cast works. thank you experts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use some simple approach like:

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(size);
```

Or manually using the stringstream:

```
static_cast<std::stringstream>(std::stringstream() << size).str()
```

The operator for numbers is a member, so it should work on temporary even in C++03; some other overloads are free functions and in C++03 those don't accept temporary, but you can use `std::stringstream().flush()`, which returns *lvalue* reference and than all `operator<<` overloads work.

But it's not just plain number. It's file size. So it's quite likely you should be rounding it and handling kB/MB/GB/KiB/MiB/GiB units. In which case have a look at [libkibi](https://launchpad.net/libkibi).