# How can I concatenate float with string?

Tags: c++, concatenation

I tried this:

```
ostringstream myString;
float x;
string s;
if(x)
  myString<<x;
else
  myString<<s;
return myString.str();
```

But it doesn't work. 
My goal is to concatenate into myString, a float and a string, with a space between them, before testing if one of them is NULL.

Comment: The `if` statement chooses between adding `x` and adding `s`.

Comment: Describe `"doesn't work"`.

Comment: While not a `float` the same techniques can be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313

Comment: Visual Studio just crash

Comment: Create a minimal example, 10 lines of code, which compiles and crashes. Post that so we can try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `else` inbetween? Try this:

```
ostringstream myString;
float x;
string s;
if (fabsf(x) > 1e-30){
    myString<<x << " ";
}
if(s.length() > 0)
   myString<<s;
return myString.str(); //does ostringstream has a str()-member?
```

Comment: i want to check if one of them is NULL

Comment: @user2116010 What do you mean by `NULL`? Equal to `0`? Of length zero?

Comment: x can't be `NULL`, at most `0.0f`. And s can't be `NULL`, either as it is on the stack.

Comment: `ostringstream` has a [`str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) member, returning a `string` which has a `c_str` member.

Comment: I don't know if it's right but at one point i just make s = NULL and now i want to test if it's null or not

Comment: @user2116010 `s = NULL` will set `s` to be [`empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty), but not NULL.

Comment: beware, floats should never be compared against absolute value. If that is returned from some operation, it might be almost zero, but non-zero. You might try if (fabsf(x) > 1e-30) instead of if (x). Note that std::string(NULL) will crash, so you have to check NULL before it is passed std::string. Use myString.empty() if does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 is out. Visual Studio has good support for it, and now has std::to_string(float).
After converting to string, just concatenate with the `+` operator;

```
string a = "test";
float b = 3.14f;
string result = a + std::to_string(b);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Also, you might be pleased to now the sto_ family of global functions exist, for converting from string back to a numeral type:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
ostringstream myString;
float x;
string s;
if ( x != 0)
  myString << x;
myString << " " << s;
return myString.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ostringstream myString;
float x;
string s;
myString<<x << " " <<s;
return myString.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

or use boost::lexical_cast:

```
return boost::lexical_cast<string>(x) + " " + s;
```