# MySQL query using float variables

Tags: mysql, sql, managed-c++

I'm working on a small project (my first MySQL one) and I got to a point where I'm coding a query to insert data in a table.

These are my variables:

```
float min=0, max=0, med=0, aux;
string data, stringTipo, stringPapel, stringCompanhia;
```

I converted the std::strings to System::strings using:

```
String^ sCom = gcnew String(stringCompanhia.c_str());
String^ sTipo = gcnew String(stringTipo.c_str());
String^ sPap = gcnew String(stringPapel.c_str());
String^ sDat = gcnew String(data.c_str());
```

This is my query:

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase=gcnew MySqlCommand("insert into bdi.acoes (companhia,papel,tipo,min,max,med,data) values('"+sCom+"','"+sPap,+"','"+sTipo+"','"+min+"','"+max+"','"+med+"','"+sDat+"');",conDataBase);
```

As of now, I'm working on a query to insert `data`, `stringTipo`, `stringPapel`, `stringCompanhia`, `min`, `max` and `med` into my `acoes` table.

For now I got errors related to the floats only, I do BELIEVE that my string conversion is rather fine for inserting data into my query, but any suggestions are welcome.

These are the errors I'm getting (note: all of them are the same for all floats).

> error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const char [4]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i concatenate float with string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385378/how-can-i-concatenate-float-with-string)

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to perform `string+float`, which C++ doesn't like. This error has nothing to do with SQL.