# Display an Integer using messageBox() Function in C?

Tags: c, winapi

I had been displaying String uptill now using messageBox(). How can I display an integer using this function? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
int message=1;
MessageBox(NULL,
           (LPCSTR)message,
           "Display",
            MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the `int` into a string. In C, you can use [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", message); 
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Display", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

and in C++ there are several options (see [Append an int to a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313) for suggestions) for storing an `int` in a `std::string` then use `std::string::c_str()` in the call to `MessageBox()`.

Comment: I am working on WIN32 API using C and I want my data to be displayed on Window that is why I was using MessageBox(). Can sprintf() be used to display data on a Window? :(

Comment: @AyeshaHassan Read and understand the answer. Learn what `sprintf` does. It outputs text to a buffer. What you do with that text is up to you. One possibility is to send it to `MessageBox`.

Comment: @hmjd:
Thank you so much for hte help. Your answer solved my problem :)