# Taking an Integer Input through a Edit Box using sendmessage() function in WIN32 API (C)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sendmessage

Im using WIN32 API. I want to take an integer lets suppose 1000 as input through an edit box. I am Using sendmessage() function for taking input but it can take only string input. How can I take an integer as input?

Comment: Fetch the string, attempt to convert it to an integer. (The ES_NUMBER style may be applied to the control to allow only numeric input (still returned as a string, not guaranteed to be numeric (eg paste)))

Comment: You should read this [convert string to integer sscanf or atoi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/convert-string-to-integer-sscanf-or-atoi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string inputted in edit box to an integer like this e.g.:

```
int n = atoi(myString);
```

Comment: You may also know the answer to my [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430935/display-an-integer-using-messagebox-function-in-c/15430989?noredirect=1#15430989) as well. Please have a look!

Comment: @duDE it is remiss of you to mention `atoi` without describing all its flaws.

Comment: What are the flaws of atoi ? :(