# Function to convert double/int into string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am a beginner in c++, so the answer maybe obvious.

I have two functions - one is able to convert int into string and the other is able convert double into string. It would be more elegant however to unite these two into one. I have tried it with the code below, but it yields an error: ‘number’ was not declared in this scope

```
string number_into_string (void* data, int psize)
{
    if (psize == sizeof(int))
    {
        int* number; number =(int*)data;
    }
    if (psize == sizeof(double))
    {
        double* number; number = (double*)data;
    }
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << number;
    string str = convert.str();
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    double x =1000;
    int y = 5;
    string str_x = number_into_string(&x, sizeof(x));
    string str_y = number_into_string(&y, sizeof(y));
}
```

Comment: Maybe write a template instead?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516196/append-an-int-to-a-stdstring/10516313#10516313

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `number` is declared inside the `if ... {` brackets, it only exists in that space. Further, you can't have one variable have two different types in C or C++.

(If you have a C++11 compiler, you don't need to do this at all, just use `std::to_string` which exists for most standard types).

The solution is to not use pointers, and to use a template function:

```
template<typename T> string number_into_string(T number)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << number; 
    string str = convert.str();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant `ostringstream`, not `ostringstring`

Comment: Maybe you can add a specialized version for pointers, which output `*number`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Thanks. Not the first time I've made that mistake.

Comment: @johnchen902: Seems quite unnecessary. Most likely, the original number isn't a pointer in the first place - as in the example, it's got the address taken of it.

Comment: @derek: Yes, I'm assuming that OP has `using namespace std;` somewhere before the code, and didn't want to rewrite the code to look too different.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I would make the same assumption due to the use of `string`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, use the [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function.

Comment: @Derek if you have an irregular compiler using `std::fiber` will help.

Answer (score 0):

A pair of curly braces `{}` create a **nested scope** and objects created inside that scope are not visible in the outer scope. You could rearrange your code to something like this:

```
string number_into_string (void* data, int psize)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    if (psize == sizeof(int))
    {
        convert << *((int*) data);
    }
    if (psize == sizeof(double))
    {
        convert << *((double*) data);
    }
    return convert.str();
}
```

Personally, I would use a standard library function instead of (badly) reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel here is particularly messy when you consider that the standard makes no promises that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)`.  In fact, on a system with 64-bit `int`s, they quite likely *will* be the same size.  At which point things get interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being quite messy, the main reason for error is variable scope. Every variable has its scope of visibility, and it is not visible beyond that scope.

In function `number_into_string` you have 3 scopes:

1. function scope - this is the whole function `number_into_string`
2. first `if` block
3. second `if` block

Variables from function scope are visible in both `if` blocks, but not the other way around.

That means, in your code:

```
convert << number;
```

you're using variable which is not known (visible) in current scope.

The other thing is that you just **CAN'T** do this "generic values thing" in C++ without using templates or putting two copies of that "conversion code" into each if block, which woud invalidate the point of having single "conversion function".

**Also**, you **CAN'T** distinguish reliably between `double` and `int` by using `sizeof`.

Comment: You could pass `typeid(x)` by reference...which would give you a way to distinguish between `int` and `double`.  But it still seems a rather iffy idea, unless you absolutely have to have one function for whatever reason.